# Why PopUp composable is not taking the round corners in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I have used PopUp composable in my jetpack compose project. I have applied the corners to Surface inside the PopUp composable as it does not take modifier parameter itself. But it only cliping the surface and popup edge corners are still visible.

Here is my code that i tried : -

```
Popup(
        alignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Surface (
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.9f)
        ){
        Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)){
            folderAccessInstructions.forEach { string ->
                    Text(text = string)
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Surface` you can just add `.clip` and `.background` **Modifiers** to the `Column` **Composables**.

Here is a code

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Stack016() {
    Popup {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(25))
                .background(color = Color.Red)
                .padding(15.dp)
        ) {
            folderAccessInstructions.forEach { string ->
                Text(text = string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]